# Oscillator failure trap being signalled on a dsPIC33F

Tags: microcontroller

I am getting an oscillator failure trap when I try to run some code on my dsPIC33FJ128GP804.

This has me very confused. I am using the FRC with a PLL to run the chip at 36.85 MHz.

I was always under the impression that an oscillator failure trap occurs only with crystal oscillators in certain conditions, and never with an on-board RC oscillator.

How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure you are getting a oscillator failure trap?  Just because it ends up in that trap routine doesn't guarantee it got there via the trap.  Have you set a breakpoint at the trap location and examined the stack to see how it might have gotten there?

Comment: Can you think of another way it could end up there?

Comment: Huh. You're right. INTCON1bits.OSCFAIL is *not* set. Now to figure out why it is ending up there...!

Comment: The only error is DMACERR, a DMA error. But I'm not using DMA... How weird...!

Comment: @Thomas: There are lots of ways of ending up in strange locations.  On a dsPIC the most common are either W15 corruption or stack corruption, then doing a return.  Also note that you don't know how many instructions got executed before it just happened to end up in your trap routine.

Comment: @Olin Is there any way to get the dsPIC or MPLAB C30 to save a call stack? I'm getting a "<call trace not available due to optimisation>" error when I try viewing the call trace.

Comment: @Thomas: Forget about the high level language.  At the break point, look at W15 to get the current stack location and work backwards yourself from there.